# Wrap around in mongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm developing a node.js application which creates a TV schedule, I have a mongo DB with a list of channels [{number :1},{number:2}.....].
I need to support paging with a cyclic response, I.E , if we have 100 channels and a user request 5 channels starting from channel 98 , the response should be 98,99,100,1,2.(it's worth mentioning that I have no knowledge what is the last channel and if the next channel after 98 is 99 or 104) 
is there a way to achive it in a single query or must I use 2 queries?

Comment: Does each {number :1} etc correspond to an individual document in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it in 2 queries. However it looks like the majority of the time, you'll get back sufficient results in the first query, i.e. if the user queries for any of the lower channels. That depends on which channels are most popular of course. So most of the time, you won't have the performance hit of 2 queries.

You can also index the `number` field in order to improve the performance. Depending on the collection size this may be significant since this use-case will require sorting on the `number` field as well as having it in the query criteria.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mongoose you can do it with skip() statement:

```
Chanel.find({}).skip().exec(function (err, chanels) {
    // your code here
})
```

Comment: using skip will just return in this case the last 3 channels